# XAML file not working and not recognize when I create a file

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, vsto

I'm trying to create a file (.xaml), a content page, but all files I create this error occurs, how could I fix this problem?

[image]

Code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="NewOutlookAddInCreatio.Views.Contacts.ContactViewPanel">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: remove and reinstall the XF nugets, try repairing/reinstalling VS, restart VS, reboot your PC, etc.  Basically all the basic "my PC is doing weird stuff" debugging steps

Comment: Why did you add the "vsto" tag? Are you mixing technologies here by any chance?

Comment: Hi @Julian, this project is a VSTO project, in another project I work on they are already using XAML files to make the screens, so to learn more about it, I created a project to study, and in it I'm trying to do the same, but it occurs to me this error.

Comment: I suppose you've selected the wrong template for the XAML. You cannot develop VSTO projects using Xamarin.Forms, that's an incompatible technology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot develop VSTO plugins with Xamarin.Forms, that's an incompatible technology. You've probably selected the wrong template for the XAML that you want to create.

Xamarin.Forms is based on .NET Standard 2.0/2.1 while VSTO plugins require .NET Framework 4.8, which only exists for Windows.

When you create a new XAML view, make sure the template is from the same technology you're using in your project. Mixing technologies will lead to the error above. Your project is probably using Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF).

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot for the info, I'll keep an eye on that.